# images not loading in node application in IIS windows server

Tags: node.js, windows, iis

**structure**

```
->app.js
->public/images/banner.jpg
->index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<img style="width: 100%" alt="" src="/images/banner.png"/>
```

**app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

its working fine in linux and in windows server with localhost. But not loading when opening with IIS

error - cannot get http://IP/images/banner.png

the alias name is "api"

I tried http://IP/api/images/banner.png its working fine.

So how to pass alias name with the ip from iis to nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes were required in outbound rules

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>

                <rule name="testing2" preCondition="IsHTML" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script" pattern="(.*)(images|styles|scripts)(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}api/{R:2}{R:3}" />
                </rule> 
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="IsHTML">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```